# Tensorflow what operations are differentiable and what are not?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, it is hard to figure out if a function is differentiable or not. For instance, `tf.argmax` is not differentiable. I am wondering is there any documentation to specify which operations is differentiable?

Comment: There's a registry which `tf.gradients` uses to lookup the gradient function for each op. It's all Python, so no private variables, so I would start by searching for `RegisterGradient` to find where it's stored

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov , this was v. helpful

Answer (score 1):

For math operation, the gradients are registered in this file: 
`tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/math_grad.py`

For example the gradient of `tf.argmax`:

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("ArgMax")
def _ArgMaxGrad(op, grad):
  del op, grad
  return [None, None]
```

Gradients for other operation can also be found in the same folder.