# What is differentiability in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I've encountered the term *differentiability* in the documentation for TensorFlow but cannot find any definition. Most posts on SO merely ask *whether* an operation is differentiable (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841490/tensorflow-what-operations-are-differentiable-and-what-are-not) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572161/list-of-differentiable-ops-in-tensorflow)).

I have an inkling this may be related to gradient descent and the need for differentiating objective functions [?]

**QUESTION**: In any case, as a programmer, why should I care about differentiability?

Answer (score 0):

actually you need to care about differentiability of your function because when you are building a neural network, you optimize its weight using gradient decent regardless of what fancy word they are using such as Adam optimization algorithm, RMS prob, what ever, it is a gradient base method. Therefore, you need to understand what is gradient in order to understand why you need to understand differentiation.

Differentiation is a derivative that we know in calculus, so differentiable in your case means you can compute a derivative with respect to weight of your model. Any function that is differentiable is, in simple word, a connected function along given parameter. For example, if your function will output 1 when input is positive and 0 when output is negative as known as step function, technically is differentiable but you will get infinity at input around 0 that is an impulse function(you can search it online for better understanding), which you can clearly see that your graph just jump from 0 to 1 at that point, therefore your derivative (d output/ d input) is not a finite number at that point.

So coming to your question "As a programmer, why should I care about differentiability?". You may not need to understand what is differentiation if you are dealing with other application but in neural network it is crucial for us to understand about it **because** we optimize weight of neural network using a value of gradient of a loss with respect to weight (d Loss/ d weight). Therefore, if your loss function is not differentiable you end up with derivative equal to infinity, so your model will collapse with a weight of infinity and produce no useful application. Other application maybe in a research field where you have to experiment with something that involve with calculus you may need to know about your differentiability of your function.

Hope this answer your question